# First slide doesnt show in jQuery Royal Slider within tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am trying to integrate Royal Slider within my website. However I am having trouble with the first slide when the slider is within tabs on my page.

For example, you can see at http://christierichards.co.uk/slidertest/newtemplatefix.php that the slider is working perfectly (there is no styling as of yet).

On this page http://christierichards.co.uk/slidertest/newtemplate.php when you click on before and after (this is the tab I want the slider appearing in) the first slide does not show until you click tab 2 and then the height seems to appear.

I have managed to fix it within the tabs but this is only by adding a fixed height onto .rsOverflow. I cannot use a fixed height as I need the auto-height feature to work for clients to add their own photos. So I need a different way around it.

There must be a piece of conflicting code somewhere however I am stumped! Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See http://help.dimsemenov.com/kb/royalslider-jquery-plugin-issues/slider-content-area-shrinks

Answer (score 0):

The slider is being initialised while it is hidden behind a tab. Because of this, it cannot calculate its height and width, and is invisible. When you change to the next item in the slider, the heights and widths are recalculated, which is why you can see it again.

You can either add an initial height to `.rsOverflow`, or (re)initialise the slider when the tab is clicked, and the contents are made visible.

For example:

```
var sliderInitialised = false;

$j( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  activate: function( event, ui ) {
     // Check the activated tab, is the one that contains the slider

     if(!sliderInitialised) {
         // Initialise slider ...

         sliderInitialised = true; 
     }
  }
});
```

Alternatively, the slider could be initialised before all the tab contents are hidden.